# Laravel mobile number validation with format and fixed digits

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have an input `tel` type field. That is for local mobile number with the format `x-xxxx-xxx`. With this, I am getting trouble invalidation. Even I enter eight digits it is giving digits validation error.

### Validation Rule

I have tried multiple ways to validate as below but none of them works.

```
// without regex
'mobile'     => 'nullable|digits:8',

// regex one
'mobile'     => 'nullable|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|digits:8',

// regex two

'mobile'     => 'nullable|regex:/^\d{1}-\d{4}-\d{3}$/|digits:8',
```

### Input Markup

I am using [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/) js plugin, in case if it requires.

```
<div class="form-group"><label for="mobile">{{__('admin.user.profile.mobile')}}</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile"
           value="{{ isset($user) ? $user->profile->mobile : old('mobile') }}"
           placeholder="{{__('admin.user.profile.mobile')}}" data-inputmask="'mask': '9-9999-999'">
    @error('mobile')
    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

### Validation Error Message

```
The mobile must be 8 digits.
```

### DD

So here I can understand the reason, is probably it is sending number with the format. So now how can I manage to validate it?

```
array:14 [▼
  "_token" => "U5F3BkiAryYkaz75R1oraUfcx3ydz6bv6Ac7mw7K"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "email" => "super@test.com"
  "password" => null
  "password_confirmation" => null
  "role" => "super"
  "first_name" => "Katheryn"
  "last_name" => "Jones"
  "mobile" => "4-6655-499"
  "city" => "Taylorbury"
  "facebook" => "http://fritsch.com/numquam-repudiandae-consectetur-sequi-suscipit-numquam"
  "twitter" => "http://jacobi.com/"
  "youtube" => "https://dubuque.org/explicabo-autem-corporis-distinctio.html"
  "instagram" => "https://www.franecki.com/eos-non-nostrum-quia-commodi-ex-totam"
]
```

> **Question:**
>
> How to validate mobile numbers with fixed digits and format?

Comment: change to type number or get rid of the digit in the validate because regex got that covered for you

Comment: But what about without regex? That also gives the same error. I have also tried removing digits and set the max:8 still doesn't validate.

Comment: yes that because you are adding `-` (based on your regex) to the input. to digit be pass the validation should only contain number nothing else.

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara I understand but what if I don't use regex as in the first example? If I use only `digits:8` then it should work. isn't it? Because all in one, I want to fix the number/digits. I don't want to allow the user to enter more than 8 digits.

Comment: yes it should work. can you update the question with your input data dump

Comment: Cannot reach to `dd()` as it doesn't pass through validation. Let me remove validation and `dd` that I can post.

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara I have updated the question with `dd`. I understand the issue. It is sending a number with the format. That is why not passing through validation as it is not only umber but the dashes as well. So, in this case, how can I force the total phone digits limit to 8 with the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with the following rules where I change the digit rule to string as laravel has no rule for digits plus dash.

> 'mobile' =>
>   'nullable|string|min:10|max:10|regex:/^\d{1}-\d{4}-\d{3}$/',

May the above solution helps you.

**Update**

For the purpose of showing the appropriate error message to the user, you will need to create a custom rule

Run the following command

> php artisan make:rule NumericDash

Update the NumericDash.php file with the following content

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class NumericDash implements Rule
{
    private $message = "The :attribute format is invalid.";
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($digitsWithoutDash, $regex)
    {
        $this->digitsWithoutDash = $digitsWithoutDash;
        $this->regex = $regex;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value)) !== $this->digitsWithoutDash) {
            $this->message = "The :attribute must include {$this->digitsWithoutDash} digits.";
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->regex, $value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

and use the rule as below

> 'mobile' => ['nullable', 'string', new NumericDash(8,
>   '/^\d{1}-\d{4}-\d{3}$/')],

Comment: Changing the max value won't make sense for the user. It will mislead them

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have updated my answer with a custom rule. Maybe that can help.